# How many B/B+ tree will be created if I add a multi column index?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, b-tree, b-plus-tree

In mysql with InnoDB storage engine, When create a multi column index, such as (a, b, c), how many B+ tree/B tree will be create?

Explain the detail if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB creates B+trees only. There is one tree for PRIMARY index.
For every secondary index InnoDB creates one B+tee no matter how many columns are in the key.

See my slides with more examples
https://twindb.com/efficient-use-of-indexes-in-mysql/